# Best way to deal with NoneType in a list when iterating through it to export a key value in a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print a certain key:value pair from a dictionary in a list of lists. I have created a for loop to accomplish this but I get the error "TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()" when trying to iterate through this. What would be the most pythonic way to iterate through this to print out each key a in each dictionary?

```
lista = [None,None,[{a:b},{a:d}],None,[{a:f}]]
for i in lista:
    print(i['a'])
```

I'm looking to get the output of something like the following:

None

None

b,d

None

f

Comment: Just add a conditional. `if i is not None`

Comment: You'll also get a `TypeError` here. `i` will be the nested list, not the dictionary.